# qml progress in the ProgressBar is jump

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I use the `ProgressBar` as `QtQuick.Controls 1.4`.
In qml:

```
ProgressBar {
    id: myProgressBar
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    minimumValue: 0
    maximumValue: 100
    visible:true
}
```

And there a c++ class:

```
class MyProgress: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int progress READ GetProgress NOTIFY progressChanged)
public:
    explicit MyProgress(QObject *parent = 0);

public:
    int GetProgress();
signals:
    void progressChanged(const int progess);
private:
    int m_progress;

};
```

In `MyProgress`, have a `QThread` to update the 'progress'.
Then ,in qml ,I add a event handler:

```
MyProgress {
    id: progress
    onProgressChanged:{
        myProgressBar.value = progress
    }
}
```

It works.But,the progress in the `ProgressBar` looks like jump,jump,jump instead of linear increasement.
I think that bacause the progress is too fast that the GUI thread has no time to refresh.
Does anyone has some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NumberAnimation` to update progress.

Update your code like this:

```
MyProgress {
    id: progress
    onProgressChanged:{
        progressAnimation.to = progress
        progressAnimation.duration =
                (progress - myProgressBar.value) * 100 // change 100 to speed up or slow down animation.
        progressAnimation.restart()
    }
}
NumberAnimation {
    id: progressAnimation
    target: myProgressBar
    property: "value"
}
```